# Powershell - Relying on $lastexitcode

Tags: powershell

I'm executing the following 7 Zip command, which takes about 3-4 hours to finish, and then using $lastexitcode to make sure the compression was successful. Is this the right way of doing this? I'm finding the $lastexitcode not to always be 0 but the compressed file looks fine.

Could something else be modifying this exit code?

```
& $7z a -tzip -mx=1 $destinationdir\$today.zip $destinationdir\$db1 >$null 2>&1
if ($lastexitcode -ne 0){
...
```

The '>$null 2>&1' is just used so I don't see the output from 7 zip.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: About 7-zip exit codes: http://7zip.bugaco.com/7zip/MANUAL/exit_codes.htm

Comment: @DavidBrabant +1 . Here is exit code definition in the source code: [ExitCode.h](https://github.com/pornel/7z/blob/master/CPP/7zip/UI/Common/ExitCode.h).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use another approach, like:

```
$process = Start-Process notepad.exe -PassThru -Wait
```

then use the

```
$process.ExitCode
```

Try this:

```
$process = Start-Process $7z -PassThru -Wait -ArgumentList "a -tzip -mx=1 $destinationdir\$today.zip $destinationdir\$db1 >$null 2>&1"
if ($process.ExitCode -ne 0) { ....}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works, except I had to remove '>$null 2>&1' from the argument list, otherwise the exit code was always 1 or 2.